# Google Drive iOS SDK: Getting user's space available

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-drive-api

I am building an app that uses the Google Drive iOS SDK to upload files to a user's Google Drive account. Due to the size of files that are being uploaded, I would like to know how much space the user is using and has available. For example I plan to have a label in my app that shows the user is using 10gb/100gb currently.

I am guessing that there could be a way to grab this info from an initial log in, but I would like to get this information on the fly.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can query the About resource to get this info. The docs for this includes some sample code as well: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/about/get

```
#import "GTLDrive.h"
// ...

+ (void)printAboutWithService:(GTLServiceDrive *)service {
  GTLQueryDrive *query = [GTLQueryDrive queryForAboutGet];
  // queryTicket can be used to track the status of the request.
  GTLServiceTicket *queryTicket =
    [service executeQuery:query
        completionHandler:^(GTLServiceTicket *ticket, GTLDriveAbout *about,
                            NSError *error) {
          if (error == nil) {
            NSLog(@"Current user name: %@", about.name);
            NSLog(@"Root folder ID: %@", about.rootFolderId);
            NSLog(@"Total quota (bytes): %@", about.quotaBytesTotal);
            NSLog(@"Used quota (bytes): %@", about.quotaBytesUsed);
          } else {
            NSLog(@"An error occurred: %@", error);
          }
        }];
}

// ...
```